# How to write html file with a text editor

Tags: html, textedit

I am trying to write my first html document. 
Here is the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_editors.asp) to the reference.

I am using TextEdit on Max OSX 10.6 and after I save it (as an html file) it is opened by the browser by double clicking on it. However the source script text is shown instead of the html structure.
What I am getting wrong?

Comment: Before save, press control + shift+ T, to convert your file to plain text, then save the file with html extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert it to a plaintext document

Click Format and then 'Make Plain Text', then make sure to save as .html

Comment: No problem, if it's solved your issue be sure to mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Does the icon of the file has an "e". Usually these kind of files should have an icon as an e. Also make sure you are saving it as .html file. I think the actual extension of the file is hidden.